# Best way to manage banners on Wordpress

Tags: plugins, wordpress, banner-ads

I am an affiliate marketer and I am showing many product banner ads in my blog posts. 
But I am facing problems when I have a lot of posts about products reviewed. It is very difficult to manage my banners.
Can anyone tell me a quick and easy way to handle it?

I am an WordPress programmer also, I have released an easy plugin. But I don't want to tell that here. I want to know which process all of you think as the best.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the best process, but I am using an WordPress plugin to do so. 
I am using "**[WP Ad Guru](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ad-guru-lite/)**" plugin , it saves my lot of time.